# link functions wont work

Tags: html, css

My code won't work, I am trying to change the color of my links (will add more specs later) but it won't change. The functions are not performed. I tried changing classes, adding id's, but nothing works.  Could someone tell me how to fix it please.

**CSS**

```css
       a:link.NB {

         color: red;

       }

       a:visited.NB {

         color: blue;

       }

       a:hover.NB {

         color: #green;

       }

       a:active.NB {

         color: #423243;

       }
```

```html
<nav id="N_bar">
  <ul>

    <li><a class="NB" href="#">Men</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="NB" href="#">Women</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="NB" href="#">Children</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="NB" href="#">Apparel</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You need to explain the problem better, like when the colour should be changed, what triggers it. Also explain what debugging you have done and how you're testing.

Comment: It won't work as you need to wrap your style definitions into style tag and move to the head or move your style definitions to `.css` file. Also, change `<!Doctype html>` to `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: CSS doesn't have **functions**, it's a language that doesn't run programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems here.

- At the end of the CSS styles, you didn't close `#M_section`
- `#green` should be simply `green`

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzj73f89/)

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark the answer as accepted then. You have a green mark to check under the answer's score.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this

```
a.NB:link {
    color: red;
}
a.NB:visited {
    color: blue;
}
a.NB:hover {
    color: green;
}
a.NB:active {
    color: #423243;
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer, however try to explain what the original poster did wrong in the first place. For instance, you could say that he had to add to pseudo class to the class-ed element, and that `#green` is not a valid color. This way we can prevent users from simply copypasting answers. Now they also *understand* it.

Comment: The class `.NB` added after the pseudo-classes is indeed weird, but actually that was not the cause of the error. There are not present in the fiddle from my answer, but I was surprised to notice that it works also by appending the class after the pseudo-class. See this [version of my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzj73f89/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this code .I hope solve your problem :

It's your code I'm just change     `#green` to     `green` 
and close     `#M_section`

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
    }

body{
        background-image:url("Aba2.jpg");
    text-align:center;
    }
    header, section, footer, aside, nav{display:block}

    #Wrapper{
     border: 2px solid blue;
     width:1000px;
     margin:20px auto;


    }
    #H_wrap{
     padding:10px;
     border:2px solid yellow;
     background-image:url("Abracci1.jpg");
    background-repeat:repeat-x;


    }

    #M_head{
    padding:10px;
    font:italic bold 34px/30px "Times New Roman" Times, arial;
    Text-align:center;
    color:#000000;
    text-shadow:2px 2px #999999;
    text-decoration:underline;

    }

    #N_bar {
    padding:20px;
    text-align:center;
    word-spacing:6em;
    font:italic bold 25px/30px "Times New Roman" Times, arial;
    text-shadow:3px 3px #999999;
    }

     a.NB:link {
     color:red;
    }
     a.NB:visited{
     color:blue;
    }
     a.NB:hover{
     color:green;
    }
     a.NB:active.NB{
     color:#423243;
    }


    #N_bar li{
    display:inline-block;
    }

    #M_section{
     background-image:url("Aba3.jpg");
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
</style>
    <meta charset="uft-8"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="Abracci_main.css"/>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id="Wrapper">
       <div id="H_wrap">

         <header id="M_head">
         Abracci
         </header>


         <nav id="N_bar">
             <ul>

                 <li><a class="NB" href="###">Men</a></li>
                 <li><a class="NB" href="##">Women</a></li>
                 <li><a class="NB" href="#$">Children</a></li>
                 <li><a class="NB" href="#@">Apparel</a></li>
             </ul>
         </nav>
         </div>
         <section id="M_section">


         </section>
         <aside id="M_aside">

         </aside>
         <footer id="M_footer">

         </footer>

      </div>



</body>
</html>
<HTML>
```

If after a once those color doesn't change .clear your browser history .